# How to define document ordering based on filter parameter

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi Elasticsearch experts.

I have a problem which might be realted to the fact I am indexing DB relational data.

My scenario is the following:

I have two entities:

documents and meetings.

Documents and meetings are independent entities. Although it is possible to assign documents to meetings in a given order.

We are using a join table for this in the DB.

```
    meetings(id,name,date)
    document(id,title,author)
    meeting_document(doc_id,meeting_id,order)
```

In elasticsearch I am indexing the documents_id as NESTED property of the meeting

meeting example:

```
    {
     id: 25
     name:"test",
     documents: [22,12,24,55]
    }
```

I will fetch the meeting, after this I would like to send a request to the documents filtering on document.id and asking elasticsearch to return the list in the same order I passed in the list of ids to the filter.

What is the best way to implement this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you indexing only the document id in a nested property of the meeting? In this case, it could be a bit overkill to use a nested type as ElasticSearch handles multi valued fields pretty well. A string field not_analyzed could be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice Question, 
I've spent some time figuring a solution for you and come up with a solution, It might be tricky one but works.

Lets have a look to my query,

I've used [script score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_script_score), for sorting by user defined list.

```
POST index/type/_search
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "script_score": {
                  "script": "ar.size()-ar.indexOf(doc['docid'].value)",
                  "params": {
                     "ar": [
                        "1",
                        "2",
                        "4",
                        "3"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "filter": {
      "terms": {
         "docid": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "4",
            "3"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

The thing you have to take care is,

send, same value for filter and in params. Like in the above query.

This returns me hits with doc ids, 1, 2, 4, 3 .

You have to change field name inside script and in filter, and you can use `termQuery` inside query object.

I've tested the code,  Hope this helps!!
Thanks

Comment: Hi,Thanks for this it is great! Although since I am using the _id we needed to do some tricks to order id using ES _id parameter as it is UUID encoded by default. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529701/accessing-id-or-parent-fields-in-script-query-in-elasticsearch